# Array prints weird characters such as ∟ @

Tags: c++, arrays

New to C++, making a tic tac toe game and my array seems to be printing gibberish as seen in the output section below.  How do I make it so that I can fill the array with char '.'? Using c++ 11

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Board.hpp"

//to determine win condition:
//check row
//check column
//check diagonal
//else it's a draw

int main() {
    Board board1;
    board1.print();
    board1.makeMove(0,0,'x');
    board1.print();
    if(board1.makeMove(0,0,'x'))
        std::cout<<"true"<<std::endl;
    else
        std::cout<<"false"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"finished!"<<std::endl;
}
```

Board.hpp

```
#ifndef BOARD_HPP
#define BOARD_HPP

class Board {

private:
    char grid[3][3];
public:
    Board();
    int makeMove(int xIn, int yIn,char playerTurnIn);
    void print();

};
#endif //UNTITLED_BOARD_HPP
```

Board.cpp

```
#include "Board.hpp"
#include <iostream>

/*default constructor which initializes an empty array with .*/
Board::Board() {
    char grid[3][3] = {{'.','.','.'},{'.','.','.'},{'.','.','.'}};
}

/*declare this in the board class

make sure to add Board:: for makeMove and print functions*/
int Board::makeMove(int xIn, int yIn,char playerTurnIn) {
    if (grid[xIn][yIn]=='.') {
        grid[xIn][yIn] = playerTurnIn;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void Board::print() {
    std::cout<<" 0 1 2"<<std::endl;
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        std::cout<<row<<' ';
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            std::cout<<grid[row][col]<<' ';
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;

    }
}
```

Output:

0 1 2

0   d
  
1 (   ╗

2 ∟ @
 0 1 2

0   d
  
1 (   ╗

2 ∟ @

false

finished!

Comment: Your constructor `Board::Board()` does not initialize member `grid` as you might expect. Instead it defines/initializes a local variable `grid` (which eclipses member `grid` (in this scope)). Hence, member grip is still uninitialized after construction (as PODs are left blank by default construction).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your constructor:

```
Board::Board() {
    char grid[3][3] = {{'.','.','.'},{'.','.','.'},{'.','.','.'}};
}
```

There, you are declaring and initializing a **new** array.

---

Try this instead:

```
Board::Board() : grid{{'.','.','.'},{'.','.','.'},{'.','.','.'}} {}
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/bj50Wz). Thanks @Scheff

Comment: Pay extra attention to whoan's the use of `:`. This kicks off a [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Probably one of the most useful and least taught things in all of C++.

Comment: Thanks for the help and extra material!